# How to Set WordPress Specific Category always used as Second?

Tags: php, wordpress

My question is that, by default WordPress arrange category name based on alphabets like if i have two category like "**National Flower**" "**Pakistan**" then WordPress automatically pick the "National Flower" as first category because "N" comes first before "P" and hence it display at the top as you see in the screenshot.

[image]

**Problem:** While i want to use "National Flower" category always on second number, means WordPress should pick it on second number even if i used "Pakistan" or "Uganda" WordPress should not prioritize the alphabets.

**Problem Summary:** for example i want to write post, i assigned two category "National Flower" and "Pakistan" now WordPress should get "Pakistan" category as first category and second used "national flower" category.

**Note:** I only do it for this category "National Flower" when i used it in my post, then wordpress should pick it on 2nd number even if there is used a "Z" alphabet category used along.

I hope someone would give me code or plugin to setup these things.